# How to execute this paralell task in Java8

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-8

I'm new in Java concurrency, so i ask what is the best way to perform action like this:

I have a static method which matches a sub image within an image. It looks like that:

```
public static Point match(final BufferedImage subimage, final BufferedImage image)
```

The method returns null if nothing was matched, else it returns the Point of the match.

Now I have 40 different sub images for one (big) image, which I want to match in parallel. Each second I will get a new (big) image in which I need to search those 40 smaller images over and over again. I need the return values of each call to to match method at the end of the match task in my main task, so I can analyze it. 
Furthermore I need to use as many CPU cores as possible for this task.

How can I accomplish that?
I have read a lot about ExecutorService, Task, Runnable and so on. Most examples only show how to print something on the console in paralles. I am really confused which way I should go in my scenario: How to pass the values and how to get the results? How should the layout of the class(es) look like? Also I have no idea what is the way to go if I create 40 tasks a second (it will take some time to setup the task, right?)

Code would be great to explain it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `CompletionService`, more likely a `ExecutorCompletionService`.

```
class Matcher {
  ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  private List<BufferedImage> subimages; // populate it yourself
  public static Point match(BufferedImage subimage, BufferedImage image) {
    // Your implementation
  }
  public List<Point> match(BufferedImage image) {
    CompletionService<Point> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(threadPool);
    int size = subimages.size();
    List<Point> results = new ArrayList<>(size);
    for (BufferedImage subimage: subimages) {
      completionService.submit(()->match(subimage, image));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      Point point = completionService.take().get();
      if (point != null) {
        results.add(point);
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

If you want to use all the CPU, you probably want to change your `ExecutorService` to `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()`. Be careful with this though!

Comment: Wow, that was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I know an answer has been already accepted, but I wanted to post a more "streamy" approach to this using java-8 streams. The code is much much smaller, but should work just fine.

```
for(BufferedImage bigImage:bigImages){
    List<Point> matchingPoints = subImages.parallelStream().map((smallImage) -> match(smallImage, bigImage)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //do whatever you want to do with matchingPoints, like adding to a bigger list 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a tutorial like [this](http://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-service-tutorial)

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: then make those 50 reps :) I actually did not know about that... still this is not good for an answer, you might get down voted.

Comment: Feel free to add my "answer" as a comment and I'll delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(40);` which will create a thread pool of 40 threads. Then create a sample class like `CompareImage extends Callable` and then create 40 objects of `CompareImage` add to the `Collection`.
and then call the `invokeAll()` on `executorService` object.

```
List<Future<Point>> list = executorService.invokeAll(listOfCompareImage);
```